# Refresh method for removing jQuery UI Sortable element not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to find a way to use the refresh method of jQuery ui sortable to remove an element from my sortable set.

The only way I've found to do this is to destroy the sortable and then recreate it, but I'm surprised that there is no method that does this (the refresh method seems to suggest that could be used for this purpose but I've had no luck)

Example is here

http://jsfiddle.net/5gN3X/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use cancel to disallow sortable on items with class `.disabled`

```
$('ul').sortable({cancel: '.disabled'});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/5gN3X/3/

Comment: Thanks but I DO NOT want to remove the div. I want to keep it there, but not include it in the sortable list. I assume that refresh is also broken in earlier versions of jQuery UI because I have never been able to get it to work (try my original fiddle link with earlier versions of jQuery and the same result).

Comment: Also that bug report is 3 years old and is a jquery UI bug report - not a jquery bug report.

Comment: @calumbrodie if you do not want to remove the .disabled item from sorting, you can use cancel for sortable to disable it from sorting. Check working example at jsfiddle.net/5gN3X/3

Comment: Great! This is exactly what I was looking for - although I still don't know what the refresh method does exactly!